# Strange HTML Link Behavior

Tags: html, hyperlink, visual-web-developer-2010

I was working in HTML, when I started having trouble referencing different pages, I started using `data/css/styles.css` and that worked fine on the page in the main directory of the Website (not inside any other folders), then when I did the same thing in a sub-directory (eg. "/home/") it didn't work. So I then tried using the standard `/data/css/styles.css`, that also didn't work in either the main or sub directories. So then I tried my final attempt with `../data/css/styles.css` with luck on sub-directories but not the main. But when I the second (`/data/css...`) and the third (`../data/css`) on JSFiddle they worked fine. Is there something wrong with my compiler (Visual Studio Web Developer 2010) or is the debugging strange? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want me to post HTML just ask :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the pathname begins with `/`, it is interpreted relative to the DocumentRoot of the website. If the pathname does not begin with `/`, it is interpreted relative to the URL of the page containing the link. So if a page with path `/a/b/c.html` contains the link `dir1/dir2/foo.css`, it is converted to `/a/b/dir1/dir2/foo.css`. `../` prefixes are used to back up by a directory in the pathname, so if the page contains `../dir1/foo.css`, it's converted to `/a/dir1/foo.css`.